# Extensions for Magento Professional Edition

Tags: magento

Are ALL Community Extensions compatible with the Pro version?
I notice that some are not with the Enterprise.

I also noticed that the Pro tabs are grayed out for all extension in Magento Connect.

Answer (score 3):

Magento Inc. has [not yet completed](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/211368/) the part of Connect responsible for commercial, professional and enterprise extensions. They say to developers:

> The most you can do at this point, is write into the description that you have tested your product against (the versions you have tested against).

So you have to approach it on a per-case basis and check each extension individually. At least until the staff finally pull their collective finger out...

Comment: do they offer a trial version of PROFESSIONAL , so that i can test it with each extension i purchased? They seem to only have online demos which i'm sure dont allow extension testing.

Answer (score 3):

No.  The three applications are similar, built off the same base, and share code back and forth, but they don't offer identical APIs or features, which would be the only way for all community extensions to automatically work in the other versions.

It's up to individual extension developers to decide which version(s) they want to support.